# Why hadoop is running on other port?

Tags: hadoop2

I'm learning hadoop and just u=installed hadoop myself

So I had set up 127.0.0.1:54310/ in core-site.xml file while configuration.

But when I open this open 127.0.0.1:54310/. it shows this quote

```
"It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon."
```

Here the ports runnings

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       120452      22666/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       119197      22787/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       119235      22787/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       120744      22787/java      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54310         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       117942      22666/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       125548      22953/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::54935                :::*                    LISTEN      1001       122123      23275/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       118396      23130/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8030                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       126362      23130/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8031                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       126344      23130/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8032                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       118392      23130/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8033                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       125653      23130/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       126351      23275/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8042                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       122149      23275/java
```

But when I open 127.0.0.1:50070, it shows me hadoop page with Overview, Datanode etc tabs in it.

Could anyone explain what these ports are diff ports, how hadoop is running  on 50070 ports, as I had set up on 54310 and why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the default `dfs.namenode.http-address` is 50070. And that's in **hdfs-site.xml**

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Apparently you didn't set that property and set something else. Sounds like you set the datanode IPC address, which is 50020.

Unless you know you have a conflict on a port, don't need to change anything